# Is it possible to get data of several selected mails inside an outlook web add-in app?

Tags: outlook, add-in, outlook-addin, office-js, javascript-api-for-office

inside a Outlook COM Add-in (C#) I was able to retrieve all selected mails inside Outlook like this

```js
var selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
List<Outlook.MailItem> outlookMailList = new List<Outlook.MailItem>();
foreach (object mail in selection)
  outlookMailList.Add((Outlook.MailItem)mail);
```

to store the selected mails with some meta data inside a DMS.

Now I would like to do the same with the Javascript API for Office (office.js).

1. What is the correct entry point here? Because when I select more than one mail inside Outlook the OutlookTab-buttons inside the default ribbon get deactivated.

see also http://bettersolutions.com/javascript-api/hosts/extensionpoint.htm

2. For retrieving the mail information I have found

```js
selectedMail = Office.context.mailbox.item;
```

How can I get now the data for all marked mails in Outlook. I expected to have something like

```js
selectedMails = Office.context.mailbox.items;
// OR
selectedMails = Office.context.mailbox.selectedItems;
```

Does someone know how to retrieve the information which mails were selected to the TaskPane or maybe a CustomPane? Respectively if it is even possible?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately Office JS API built for handling a single [item](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.item.html). Handling multiple items is not possible.

If this is a new feature you want to include in the future, you may submit a feedback.

[https://officespdev.uservoice.com/](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/17211737-office-js-api-built-for-handling-multiple-items)​

Best regards

Comment: Is there any updates on this? Does now Office JS API supports multiple emails selection?

Comment: @AakashMaurya According to latest [Office Preview Requirement Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.item?view=office-js) there is no object which handles several items. Everything is still around one item at the time.